# Why did my spot request get cancelled automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spot-instances

I had requested a Spot instance for a single instance of t2.micro. An instance was assigned and the request was active. A few days later, after the instance ran for 9 days, the spot request was "cancelled". The status of the request was cancelled and the instances were terminated.

Questions:

1. Why was the request cancelled? I had set a normal bid price that of a much higher value than the spot price.
2. I checked the records, and it shows event : **bitChange** that lead to the request to move to status **closed** . Even if the bid price changed, I'm pretty sure it did not cross my bit price. as it was too high.
3. What exactly happened? Why did the instance move to close? Can someone please explain me?

[image]

Comment: A similar question was asked on AWS discussion forum back in Dec 2020, and was never answered.  See [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=332765). 
 I'd approach AWS support.

Comment: Hey @AviNehama Thanks for the ref. I have updated the post there and asked the same. I'll try to contact AWS support as well.

Answer (score 2):

As a best practice for Spot, don't set a **maximum price** at all. it will be set to on-demand price by default and Spot prices can't go above on-demand prices so you won't be interrupted because of price change.

The **only** reason you will be interrupted is when EC2 needs this capacity back for on-demand customers, which is the reason for Spot discounted prices.

Use **Auto Scaling groups** and **Spot Fleet** to launch and **maintain** a target capacity, and to automatically request instances to replace any that are interrupted.